# how to solve android 10 storage permission denied in python kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy

I'm new here. Recently I'm developing android app based on Python Kivy. my app is about downloading post from Instagram and save it in android local storage. Its work fine in my android (Oppo A3s with android 8.1) but when I tested it to my friend's phone, which is newer version of android than me (android 10) its failed. When I run adb, it said permission denied. I was wondering and find solution on Internet and they said android 10 and newer not allowing to write directly to the storage (example: /sdcard/DCIM/Camera)

my question is: How to solve this and how to write file to /sdcard/DCIM/Camera in android 10? or how to save file in public storage that other app can use that files too?

Thanks lot for help :)

Comment: Request legacy external storage in manifest file and you are ready.

Comment: yeah but can you show me the way to do it in python kivy?

Comment: No i cant as i do not program in Kivy.

Comment: hey, btw thanks for giving me idea. i search on internet and found where is AndroidManifest.xml file. ;)

Comment: @wanZ how did you edited  AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: go to .buildozer/android/platform/<Build version>/dists/<your app>

Answer (score 0):

So if ur app is made from kivy or kivymd
To enable access to android 10 internal storage ,get ur compiled apk, decompile it with `apktool` using -`-apktool d <APK name>` then open it's `AndroidManifest.xml` file and add `requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `<application` >tag such that it looks like below

```
<manifest ... >
  <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
       Android 10. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Then recompile with `apktool b <name of folder with decompiled files>` ,sign the APK with an apksigner and this will do the trick

Remember that it's important to sign the newly compiled apk and the compiled APK is found in the **dist** subfolder in the folder containing the decompiled files